# Simple pointer to array

Tags: c++

What does the following code do?

```
obj *x = new obj[100];
delete x; // Note the omission of []
```

Does it delete only the first element in the array?

Comment: It would likely delete the entire array but not in the way you'd expect. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though it is undefined behavior, you should probably take note of the most likely result (for the sake of debugging such issues).

When you create an array via `new Object[100]`, the memory is first allocated. The default behavior (provided there were no overrides to the default allocator) is to simply call `malloc(100 * sizeof(Object))`. After that, the constructor for `Object` needs to be called on each `Object`-sized region. This is an important detail: **the memory is allocated once**, but the constructor is called in 100 locations.

When a block is allocated via `malloc`, it cannot be freed in pieces. Only a call to `free(block)` will release that memory. The C++ keyword `delete` internally calls `free` if the keyword `new` calls `malloc`. So, the proper way to delete an array is to call `delete [] array`. So, what happens if you call `delete array`? The likely answer is that the memory will be freed (all of it, not just the first element), but only one destructor will be called: the first element's destructor.

Obviously, there are lots of facts to consider. `new` and `delete` are not necessarily bound to `malloc` and `free`. They may use system calls unique to a specific architecture or operating system. (Windows, in particular, has a whole set of heap management functions outside of `malloc` and `free` in its C API.) I simply demonstrated the example with `malloc` and `free` because that is what I have seen the most often when stepping through code. Visual Studio, for example, lets you step into `new` calls and actually see the `new` function code. (That's another important detail. `new` and `delete` are simply function calls, which you can even override in many cases.)

---

You can demonstrate this concept with this little program. Simply create an `Object` class that outputs something during the constructor and outputs something else during the destructor.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Object* o = new Object[4];
    delete o;
    return 0;
}
```

I ran it, and sure enough: the constructor was called 4 times, and the destructor was called once.

Comment: One would think the correct answer would deserve more upvotes...   hmmm.  Groupies on the 82k much?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 The checkmark does not necessarily indicate the correctness of an answer, it simply shows which answer the OP found the most useful in addressing the problem. In this particular case, I would seriously doubt the validity of an advice that relies on undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh I understand that.  Just seems like there was a large wave of votes your way where this question actually answers the OP's question.  Note that he also says that this is an undefined behavior.

Comment: "Even though it is undefined behavior, you should probably take note of the most likely result (for the sake of debugging such issues)." No, you absolutely should not: the only valid way of dealing with undefined behavior is avoiding undefined behavior. Learning about the "most likely behavior" does not translate well to other systems, ultimately providing a disservice to whomever learns it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's not "advice". The question was simple: what happens when you do this? Your response did not answer the question. You simply said, "Don't do that." I agree that no one should *ever* do  this, but it is perfectly reasonable to ask: what would happen in this case?

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw "Don't do that" is the only answer that stands a chance of being correct. All other answers (including yours) are misleading at best.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You misunderstand. If someone were to accidentally type `delete` instead of `delete []`, you should be aware of the behavior in order to track it down. How is your answer helpful at all? The question is about what happens, not whether it is morally acceptable to do so.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I want to know why you think your response deserves to be the "correct answer" when you obviously didn't answer the initial question. Whereas TheBuzzSaw did answer the question and didn't make any assumptions of what the questioner was trying to learn.

Comment: @MattCase It's not "correct", it's "accepted", and that is not what I am arguing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I covered all my bases. My answer is very much correct. Go run a sample program if you don't believe me. Again, you are giving the "C++ standard" answer; I'm giving the practical answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am fully aware that the check mark indicates that the answer was "accepted" and not necessarily "correct". But what makes you think that you're answer is correct? if anything you should not have posted an answer because what you posted is not an answer it is a comment or a side note. Next time just do us all a favor and make a comment on the question instead of responding to it with something that isn't an answer.

Comment: @MattCase "what makes you think that you're answer is correct?" How's "C++ standard" sound for an answer? "Next time just do us all a favor [...]" speaking for yourself (rather than pretending to speak for everyone) is a kind of behavior highly valued in this community.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's the problem here. Everyone agrees about what the C++ standard says. The OP asked a very clear question: what happens when you call `delete` on a `new[]`. It did not ask what happens only in accordance with the C++ standard.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Speaking for yourself is highly valued, I'll give you that. But what is even more so is knowing what is happening at a lower level. What is not highly valued and highly frowned upon is the behavior of simply making blanket statements like "The code above exhibits undefined behavior".

Comment: @MattCase There is a big difference between knowing what happens at low level in cases when the behavior is defined, and knowing what happens at low level in cases when the behavior is undefined. You can and should know the former; you cannot and should not attempt to pretend that you know the later. "The code above exhibits undefined behavior" is enough to know *what* to fix; `valgrind` is enough to find the exact place of *where* to apply your fixes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight There is absolutely nothing wrong with being curious about what is actually happening, even in areas that are "officially" undefined.  TheBuzzSaw never pretended to know what always happens, he simply provided a way to see some of what happens under whatever compiler you happen to be using, and satisfying curiosity is both a good and necessary exercise.  The fact is, you did not answer the OP's question, you just told him he should never do that.  TheBuzzSaw both pointed out that you shouldn't do it normally, and then answered the question.

Answer (score 11):

The code above exhibits undefined behavior: it should be

```
delete[] x;
```

because the allocation was done with `new[]`.

When you use the correct operator, the entire array pointed to by the pointer gets deleted:

```
obj *x = new obj[100];
delete[] x; // The entire array gets deleted
```

Comment: @Vsevywniy: Yes. Destructor will be called.

Comment: As dasblinkenlight said, your code is undefined and the effect will be compiler-dependent. Yes the destructor of obj will be called, but as you do not know how the compiler allocates arrays, you cannot say that e.g. the first element of the array will be destroyed.

Comment: If you use delete[] destructor will be called for all elements. For your code as @dasblinkenlight told, it's undefined.

Comment: @Vsevywniy As it is always the case with undefined behavior, nobody can say with certainty how your program will fail, or even if it is going to fail at all. Anything could happen, from a crash to a call of destructors on all elements, but there is absolutely no way to give a definitive answer.

Comment: It should be an RAII container, not `delete[]`.

Comment: @DeadMG In all fairness, the virtues of the RAII concept have nothing whatsoever to do with the OP's question. He's asking what happens if he misleads a compiler that has no way of knowing `obj *x = new obj()` from `obj *x = new obj[100]`, and the answer is "it's undefined behavior".

Comment: You're answer does not answer his question. You are making an assumption of what the guy wanted to know. Even though what you said is technically accurate you completely missed the point. He asked "Does it delete only first array's element?" and you answered by simply indicating how to delete the entire array appropriately. TheBuzzSaw's answer is much more appropriate.

Comment: @MattCase Of course it does! The answer is "it's undefined". The TheBuzzSaw's answer is both misleading and dangerous, as is any suggestion to rely on "knowing" what happens when you invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It is undefined in accordance to the C++ standard. That doesn't answer the question. My question is not misleading; it is FACT! Again, we're not talking about doing this on purpose. We're talking about recognizing its behavior in the case of an accident. Like I said, my answer is to help someone DEBUG THE MISTAKE.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw "It is undefined in accordance to the C++ standard" C++ standard is the only thing in accordance to which the behavior can be defined or undefined. Any suggestion that an undefined behavior can go this way or that way is a rather dangerous suggestion.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You are ignoring my posts. I am aware of what the C++ standard says. You are also still implying that I *recommend* coding this way. I don't. The question was simple: what happens when you `delete` a `new[]`? It's perfectly valid research. I made it very clear that *sometimes* this is what happens. Your answer is "remain in ignorance".

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw Of course you are not recommending to code this way, it's the advise to learn about "the most likely result" that I find misleading and dangerous. This is the kind of "knowledge" that remains relevant only as long as you stay with the same version of the same compiler. The moment you migrate or upgrade you would need to "unlearn" the results of the "perfectly valid research".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's not misleading: it's the truth. Go test it. It's not dangerous: I made it clear that this behavior is not constant. It's good to be aware of the behavior possibilities to help diagnose problems. When you call `delete` on a `new[]`, *something* happens. Why is the OP not allowed to ask what that something is?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Your answers continue to imply that I am telling the OP that calling `delete` on `new[]` is perfectly safe and good as long as you know what's happening. I'm not. What if the OP is diagnosing a bug? Is it so wrong to ask what happens? According to you, since it falls outside the C++ standard, we should just throw our hands up in the air and give up. We're not allowed to know what happens, so we just have to accept that our program crashes for no reason whatsoever.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw It's not "**the** truth", it's "one possible version of the truth", and that is precisely why it is dangerous. The OP is allowed to ask "what that something is"; the trouble is, there is no reliable or correct answer to this question. Any non-standard behavior can and will change without notice, leaving the unsuspecting reader thinking that he knows "the truth", while he knows only one of its versions.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I said all that. Does my post say that this and only this will happen? Nope. So, again, yes, it is the truth. I added all the proper stipulations: it will not always behave this way. Why is that so hard for you to grasp?

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw It's not hard for me to grasp, I understand what you are saying one hundred percent. I am simply strongly disagreeing with your assertion that it is somehow useful to know precisely in what way does undefined behavior manifests itself in this particular case.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's not useful to know? How does one debug a `new[]` and `delete` mismatch without this knowledge?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But valgrind is not in the C++ standard!

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw Neither is the behavior that your answer describes :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight My answer is *factually* correct. I both acknowledged that it is undefined behavior and that it is subject to change at any time. From there, it is fact that many compilers perform a simple `malloc` and `free`. That is a fact, sir. There is no "thinking I know the answer". That *is* the answer for many compilers.

Comment: OK, folks, this is getting a little out of hand. If you want to keep having this discussion, I suggest moving this to chat and laying off the personal insults.

Answer (score -1):

This code was exhibiting definite behaviour on GCC i.e was deleting first object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

class myclass {

public:

int i;

myclass(){

std::cout <<"myclass constructed \n";

this->i = rand() % 100;

std::cout<<this->i;
}

~myclass(){

std::cout <<"myclass destroyed\n";

std::cout<<this->i;
}       
};

int main()
{

myclass * pt;

srand ( time(NULL) );   

pt = new myclass[3];

delete pt;

return 0;
}
```